# What does colluded truncation attack mean?

Tags: encryption, terminology

I'm doing my final year engineering project. I went through some ieee papers and came across something called colluded truncation attack. Can someone explain what it is. I'm planning to do the project in mobile agents platform using Aglets (java mobile agents). Concept is something like this - a mobile agent moves from one host to another. i must be able to make some attack on it to retrieve the contents in it. And must also find a way to send this data securely.

Answer (score 3):

Have a read of this paper from the [University of Missouri-Kansas City](http://h.web.umkc.edu/harnl/papers/C58.pdf) for a bit of info on this - it doesn't go into depth on the problem of colluded truncation attacks, but has some mitigation theory.

The idea is that where mobile agents are collecting data, an attacker may try to truncate data in order to alter results, hide information etc. This is usually protected against by having data signed at each server, on receipt and sending.

A collusion between 2 or more hosts may be able to still alter the data in a way beneficial to them without it being discovered. This is a colluded truncation attack.